# How To change Bundle Products price to three decimal

Tags: price, bundled-product

I want all bundle product price should be like: 55.225 including sales or order pages in admin panel

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, you would need to take a close look at `lib/Zend/Currency.php`

Further investigating you would need to adjust the precision to 3 instead of 2:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.currency.options.html

This thread has more details on implementing such as well, it looks as though Magento also does some price formatting else where also:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/16337/

`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Price.php`

`return number_format($value, 3, null, '');`

I know its not a definitive answer but hopefully leads you in the right direction.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980164/magento-how-do-i-set-the-product-price-to-4-decimal-places#answer-6984639).

Comment: Ensure that you don't overwrite the core file but extend the class if you're going to do it programatically.

Comment: Thanks For Your Answer Adarsh khatri But for catalog products i have already done it and this is my bolg post link can you pls describe the all steps for bundle products: https://developersushant.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/magento-change-currency-to-3rd-decimal-point/